# How to generate dependency graph by class only for one project?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, dependency-graph

If I use:

> Architecture -> Generate Dependency Graph -> By Class

it generates the graph for the entire solution.

Is there a way to cause VS to generate the dependency graph only for classes from a certain project?

I tried generating only for a certain project using `Architecture Explorer -> Create a new graph document from all the selected nodes` (with and without having <kbd>ctrl</kbd> pressed) but it only generates either classes with no connection between them or classes connected to namespaces.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 3):

Try out Resharper 8 (http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/) it has lot's of features regarding dependency graphs.

Comment: this does not seem to allow showing dependency graph by class, it shows dependency by project/library

Answer (score 1):

unloading the projects that you don't want included appears to work in VS2012.

try in VS2010?